# Solr - How to differentiate between to* and to *

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I have the following indexed documents in my `Solr 4.0` setup with their title field having documents -

1. To Work
2. Topology
3. ... < many more >

I have the title field as `solr.StrField` (String). I also have the `copyField` of the `title` field in another field `title_token` of type `solr.TextField` with the tokenizer  `StandardTokenizerFactory` and a filter `LowerCaseFilterFactory`.

When a user searches for just `To`, in order to get the documents whose `title` starts with `To`, I query `Solr` with `title:To*`. Works fine. Displays document 1 and 2.

However, when the user searches for `To` (with a space after To), i send this query to `Solr` like `title:To *` (with a space between To and *). Ideally only the 1st document should be displayed. However all the documents are displayed.

When I query `title:To *` along with  `&debugQuery=true` the query is parsed as `"parsedquery_toString":"title:to title:*"`.

Since `title:*` would display all the documents, all documents are displayed.

How do I query for `To *` which would give me all documents having `title` starting with `To` (with a space after To), in this case the document 1 should be dispalyed?

I am using `Embedded Solr server` running in my `Web App` running on `Tomcat`. I use `solrj` to query and fetch results.

Comment: have you tried with quotes "to *"?

Comment: Yes. With quotes * is not treated as a wild card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should escape the white space `field:to\ *` so that query formed is `title:to *`
Else it would match all documents.

Also [Wildcard Queries](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Wildcard+Queries) :-
Note that wildcards are not supported within quoted phrases. They will be treated as if they were white space.

On prefix, wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the search word.
So `To*` would not match the index document if you lower case filter.